# Getting a list of numbers from 0 to n, which has no adjacent consecutive numbers and the value of the number is not equal to its index

Tags: python, arrays, list, backtracking

So, I want a function to return a list (l), which has values (0, 1, 2, 3, ... , n) but consecutive numbers cannot be adjacent to each other. And the value of the number cannot be equal to its index.

For eg. for n = 4,

```
def main(n)
    ---code goes here---
    return l
print(main(4))
>>>[1, 3, 0, 2]
```

Thanks much

Edit: 
I have written this much as of now, but I'm not sure if I'm on the right track...

```
def sameRowColumn(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if i == lst[i]:
            return True
def sameDiagonal(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        for j in range(len(lst)):
            if i != j:
                if i + lst[i] == j + lst[j] or i - lst[i] == j - lst[j]:
                    return True
# def backTrack(lst1, lst2, dist):
#     for i in range(len(lst1)-1, (len(lst1)-1)-dist, -1):
#         lst2.append(lst1[i])
#         lst1.remove(lst1[i])

def queensList(N):
    l = []
    nums = [i for i in range(N)]
    while len(l) != N and len(nums) != 0:
        l.append(nums[0])
        print(l, nums)
        if sameRowColumn(l) or sameDiagonal(l):
            l.remove(nums[0])
            nums.insert(len(nums), nums.pop(0))
            print(l, nums)
        else:
            nums.remove(nums[0])
            print(l, nums)
    return l, nums

print(queensList(4))
```

Comment: First show some effort yourself. What have you done to solve this problem?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Here, I've added the code I had written so far. I'm so sorry! I'm new to this site.

Comment: @hvrc check my answer its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here this works tested in python 3.6

This prints all odd numbers then all even numbers in reverse and if the last even number is equal to the index we interchange n-1 and n

```
n=input("Enter ur number: ")
n = int(n)
l =[0]*n
y=1
z=0
for x in range(n):
    if y<=n and x+1<=n/2:
        l[x]=y
        y=y+2
    else:
        if(x==z):
            l[x]= l[x-1]
            l[x-1] = z
            z=z+2
        else:
            l[x]=z
            z=z+2
print(l)
```

Comment: Why do you solve obvious homework where the OP has shown zero effort?

Comment: maybe the op isnt able to solve it and he needed help and i like solving problems and was free

Comment: usually the policy is not to answer homework questions before the OP has provided their own attempt. Since otherwise we attract more and more lazy students that are looking for easy ways to solve homework.

Comment: ohk i will follow that from the next time

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem he added the code he wrote so far BTW see the edited question

Comment: And for `n = 5`, it produces `[1, 3, 5, 0, 2]`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks for the info i updated that now it works

Comment: no, a constraint is that at index `i`, the number `i` should not be in the array, and for `n = 5`, we get `[1, 3, 0, 2, 4]`.

Comment: No we get [1,3,0,4,2] looks like you didn't look up the edited code before your comment @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154979/discussion-between-sumit-and-willem-van-onsem).